# undefined method `stripe_id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having this issue and each time I just remove stripe_id then I don't have the error but I get back to the home page without the payment working... Some freelancer did this part and I can't figure out why it doesn't work on my computer but works fine on a server or the freelancer's computer.. the code won't work on any of my computers.. Anybody knows what's the issue I been trying to figure this one out. On the server the payment works...

This is my controller

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :webhooks
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:webhooks]

  def new
  end

  # this is for recursive
  def subscription_payment
    begin
      stripe_id = Plan.find_by_plan_type(params[:plan_type]).stripe_id
      # stripe_id = Plan.find(params[:plan_id]).stripe_id
      @plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(stripe_id)
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :description => "Customer for #{params[:stripeEmail]}",
        :source => params[:stripeToken],
        :email => params[:stripeEmail]
      )

      stripe_subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(:plan => @plan.id)
      @payment = current_user.payments.new(customer_id: customer.id, card_exp_month: customer.sources[:data][0]['exp_month'], card_exp_year: customer.sources[:data][0]['exp_year'], card_id: customer.sources[:data][0].id, customer_subscription_id: stripe_subscription.id, plan_id: @plan.id)
      @payment.save!

      if params[:plan_type] == "monthly"
        current_user.build_user_plan(plan_id: @plan.id, plan_expiry: Date.today+1.months).save
      elsif params[:plan_type] == "annual"
        current_user.build_user_plan(plan_id: @plan.id, plan_expiry: Date.today+1.years).save
      else
        current_user.build_user_plan(plan_id: @plan.id).save
      end

      flash[:notice] = 'You have successfully got the premium.'
        redirect_to root_path
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  # Method responsbile for handling stripe webhooks
  # reference https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks
  def webhooks
    begin
      event_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
      event_object = event_json['data']['object']
      #refer event types here https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types
      case event_json['type']
        # when 'invoice.payment_succeeded'
        #   handle_success_invoice event_object
        # when 'invoice.payment_failed'
        #   handle_failure_invoice event_object
        # when 'charge.failed'
        #   handle_failure_charge event_object
        when 'customer.subscription.deleted'
        when 'customer.subscription.updated'
      end
    rescue Exception => ex
      render :json => {:status => 422, :error => "Webhook call failed"}
      return
    end
    render :json => {:status => 200}
  end

end
```

This is my the sign in button where the amount is charged.

```
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                      <%= form_tag subscription_payment_path, method: :post do %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :plan_type, "monthly" %>
                        <script class="stripe-button"
                          data-amount="1000"

                          data-currency="CAD"

                          data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"

                          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"

                          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js">
                        </script>
                      <% end %>
                    <% else %>
                      <a href="/users/sign_in" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round">
                        Subscribe
                      </a>
                    <% end %>
```

Comment: Post your error message

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing `undefined method 'stripe_id' for nil:NilClass`, then that means `Plan.find_by_plan_type(params[:plan_type])` is likely returning `nil`. And you can't get the `stripe_id` of `nil`.

Are you sure that you have database records on your local machine, in particular `Plan` records with `plan_type`?

If your want to handle the scenario where a `Plan` is not found, given the `plan_type`, then you could try:

```
plan = Plan.find_by_plan_type(params[:plan_type])
raise SomeSortOfError if plan.nil? # make sure to rescue accordingly
stripe_id = plan.stripe_id
```

Comment: I looked and yes the plan_type is in the schema.
````
  create_table "plans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "plan_name"
    t.string "plan_type"
    t.string "amount"
    t.string "stripe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: @DimX It's not enough for `plan_type` to be in the schema. You actually need to have `Plan` records in your database. If you go into your `rails console` and do `Plan.where(:plan_type => 'monthly')` do you get any records back? If not, then that's where your problem is. You need to have records with `:plan_type = 'monthly'`, otherwise your `find_by_plan_type` call will return `nil`.